# How is Missandei's name pronounced?

Tags: game-of-thrones

How is the name Missandei from Game of Thrones supposed to be pronounced? I've heard characters like Grey Worm and Daenerys pronounce it very differently to how the showrunner pronounces it here:

(3 minutes and 13 seconds in).

Comment: I would assume a native Essosi and a Valyrian noblewoman to have a better grasp of it than two English dudes.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson what English dudes? The show runners Benioff and Weiss are both Americans .

Comment: The language, not the region.

Answer (score 3):

> How is the name Missandei from Game of Thrones supposed to be pronounced?

From when Daenerys and Missandei first meet and Daenerys asks for her name:

If anyone is going to pronounce her name correctly, it would be Missandei herself.

(sounds like "miss-anne-daye")